# How do I get IRBRC running on Win32 for Ruby console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

Can anyone suggest some troubleshooting approaches for getting IRBRC running under Win32?  The rails console is an awesome tool and I'm attempting to extend it with more functionality.

For instance, I would like the what_method gem to load automatically.  The gem is installed but it does not load:

```
C:\...\trunk>ruby script\console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.2)
>> 3.45.what? 3
NoMethodError: undefined method `what?' for 3.45:Float
        from (irb):1
>> require 'what_methods'
=> ["DummyOut", "WhatMethods"]
>> 3.34.what? 3
3.34.round_with_precision == 3
...
=> ["round_with_precision", "round", "prec_i", ... "round_without_precision"]
>>
```

### My environment is setup as

```
C:\...\trunk>dir %HOME%
 Volume in drive C is OS
...
06/21/2009  10:29 AM    <DIR>          .
06/21/2009  09:28 AM               118 .irbrc
...
```

Environment variable path IRBRC = %HOME%\.irbrc

### .irbrc file

```
require 'irb/completion'
require 'map_by_method'
require 'what_methods'
require 'pp'
IRB.conf[:AUTO_INDENT]=true
```

### I've read the following references

http://railscasts.com/episodes/48-console-tricks

http://drnicwilliams.com/2006/10/12/my-irbrc-for-consoleirb/#irbrc_win32

http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-talk-google/browse_thread/thread/23fe3980a5a4816e

http://www.nabble.com/.irbrc-on-Windows-td23954309.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to have the 'what_methods' gem autoloaded in a Rails environment, you could just specify it via `config.gem` in your Rails config inside of RAILS_ROOT\config\environment.rb:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
...
  config.gem "what_methods"
...
end
```

or for development only, just add it in your RAILS_ROOT\config\environments\development.rb:

```
config.gem "what_methods"
```

Comment: thanks rnicholson.  I guess that will help get the gems in the console but it won't help other console settings.  But thanks for this advice, it will help.

Answer (score 1):

cd %HOMEPATH%

edit .irbrc

add stuff

Comment: I don't understand.  edit differently than I stated in the original question?

Comment: Hmm.  Yeah it *should* be loading that file and doing it all right.  A few hints might be: add some puts in that file, make sure your directory matches File.expand_path('~') [since that's where ruby will load it from], and that it's readable from within a ruby process [should be].
GL.
=r

Answer (score 1):

+1, @rogerdpack for giving me the clue I needed to get IRBRC, Wirble, etc., working on Windows XP Pro.  In my case, though, I first had to change to my %HOMEDRIVE%, which was not the "C:" drive, to get the job done.  It's all working fine, now, thanks to him!  It is not exactly obvious, on XP, how one can create files preceded by a '.'. I wasted considerable time trying to accomplish it with [File | New | Text Document] in Windows Exploder and the Context Menu; they kept telling me "You must type a file name."  the post, here, by @rogerdpack led me to use "edit" from the console and it brought up the old DOS editor, blue screen and all, and, after entering some text, using [File | Save} to ".irbrc" let me create the *nix-ed filename.  Later, I discovered that my old standby, Notepad++, and some other text editors, will also let you save files with a dot prefix.

I must say that I read a lot of misguiding posts, elsewhere, about various strategies for getting around .irbrc before this question and the post by @rogerdpack put the issue to rest!  Thanks!  Oh, I might as well mention that [Colorized Wirble in windows xp](http://www.botvector.net/2008/06/colorized-wirble-in-windows-xp.html) also has a different solution that may help some folks.

Comment: you may also like to check out an irb-alternative called Pry, that offers things like syntax highlighting, source code browsing and documentation browsing all in one package: http://pry.github.com

Comment: Well, thank you, @banister!  [Pry](http://pry.github.com/) was an easy gem to install and gives me some great functionality, indeed.  Imagine moving around with [cd and looking at things with ls](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/State-navigation)!  And the fact that you can [activate Pry from within a Ruby script](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Runtime-invocation)?  Priceless!

Answer (score 1):

Use Pry: http://pry.github.com

Lets you:

- view method source code
- view method documentation (not using RI so you dont have to pre-generate it)
- pop in and out of different contexts
- syntax highlighting
- gist integration
- view and replay history
- open editors to edit method using `edit-method obj.my_method` syntax

A tonne more great and original features

View the screencast on that link above, it also works with Rails. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your Environment Variable path for IRBRC to use `_irbrc` instead of `.irbrc` - yes even though the file in your home path is still actually called `.irbrc`. For example, my IRBRC variable is `%HOMEPATH%\_irbrc` and the file it is referring to is `C:\Users\Paul\.irbrc`.