# Rails Console Doesn't Load .irbrc While Irb Does On Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, irb

I installed Rails 3.2.8 using RailsInstaller on Windows 7 64bit (Ruby 1.9.3). I then created a .irbrc file in my %HOME% directory - `C:\Users\Username` with the following content:

```
def h obj
    puts "This object is #{obj}"
end
```

If I use irb in the command line, I can access that method in .irbrc. However, when I fire up `rails c`, the method is not accessible, which means the .irbrc file is not loaded by `rails c`.

Could anyone please help me figure out why is irb able to load the .irbrc file, but rails console is not loading it at all?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example on a Rails 3.2.1 application on Windows 7, and `.irbrc` file was loaded in the rails console.

Nothing unusual with the PATH variable; it just points to `C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin`

Try setting the IRBRC variable as Dr. Nic suggests at the bottom of this blogpost: http://drnicwilliams.com/2006/10/12/my-irbrc-for-consoleirb/

An old Stack Overflow question [How do I get IRBRC running on Win32 for Ruby console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024056/how-do-i-get-irbrc-running-on-win32-for-ruby-console) could give some clues as well.

Comment: Thanks Prakash. I have tried all of those already, but unfortunately none of those works. I don't think an IRBRC variable is necessary for the console to pick it up because irb can pick up the .irbrc file without me setting the IRBRC variable. That being said, I did try setting the variable, but that didn't work either. I tried setting it to `%HOME%\_irbrc`, `%HOME%\.irbrc` and `%HOME%\\_irbrc` along with some other variations in case Windows prefers another way of stating directories. Did you do `gem install rails` or did you use the rails installer?

Comment: I started with the rails installer.